# I eliminated vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic in order to avoid the hanging and now is broken

Tags: kernel

I dont know how to solve the problem.

vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic was getting frozen whenever I tried to install something so I decided to eliminate it from /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic

Now, obviously... I am stuck,

How can I get back the vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic or move to a previous vmlinuz version?

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a fair bit of time removing 4.13.0-38 after a tonne of problems (dpkg and initramfs).  I decided to use kernel 4.13.0-36 instead as it was already installed.  Here's how I done so:

Check which alternative kernel is installed:

```
sudo dpkg -l linux*
```

The entry I wanted was linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic

Backup grub:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

Edit grub:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub    #use any editor
```

Change line 6 to:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-36-generic"
```

This ensures future updates don't affect the boot order.

Save and run update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

Check kernel version

```
uname -a
```

Optionally remove the broken kernel:

```
sudo dpkg -l linux*
sudo apt-get purge -y <all kernel 4.13.0.38 packages>
```

Finishing up:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Some troubleshooting/handy commands I used along the way or if things didn't go as planned:

```
sudo pkill dpkg*
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
ls /boot
```

Hope that helps one way or another.